# external displays not appearing in gnome settings

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I am running Ubuntu Mate 20.04. I have a second monitor attached to my laptop via HDMI and want to change its position. I was able to do this in 18.04 with the old "Displays" option, but can't figure out how to do this with the new gnome-settings.

`xrandr` returns:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
...
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
....
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The following is all I see under "displays":
[image: screenshot of 'displays' options in Settings]

Answer (score 0):

```
xrandr --output eDP  --auto --output HDMI-A-0 --primary --left-of eDP
```

where eDp and HDMI are my monitor names derived from

```
xrandr
```

you can make a Ubuntu shortcut key for this command, or a script.